# Code in java that will get the numerical value in a textbox?

Tags: java, netbeans, textbox, numerical

[image: Textbox Example]

Is there a way that I can get the numerical value from the textbox? The value in the textbox is in currency form. I want to multiply the value from this but I get an error because there is letters "Php". Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you're actually asking how to remove all non-numeric characters from a string? Use a regex.

Comment: Yes. Sort of. I just need a way to multiply the value inside that textbox.^^ Anyway that could help. What is regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like SLaks suggested.

**Here is an example:**

```
//Replaces all non-numerical characters except periods with "".
String str = "Php1,500.00";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Note: The regular expression above removes negative signs.

Have fun.

Comment: @JMTrasfiero `^\\d` means anything that isn't a digit. So this regex allows you to replace all non-digit characters with the empty string.